# Wizard clothing for warm weather

Tags: internal-consistency, society, magic, clothing

Wizards in fantasy worlds are very often portrayed in thick robes and hats (and of course long beards and hair for the men). These don't seem very practical for summers or any kind of hot weather (assuming wizards can't just have all their clothing enchanted with on-going air-conditioning effects.)

What is a realistic hot-weather outfit for a wizard, given their typical, particular needs (freedom of movement for casting, various books, potions, reagents, etc.)? Bonus points for example images and/or references to realistic/historical fashion.

Comment: What do humans do ?  Extra layers in winter (or at night !), maybe a cloak or hooded garment as well.  Adapt idea to wizards, keeping in mind that what you think wizard beings look like is going to be different from what I think they look like.  What materials and other factors that control availability are also arbitrarily your choice.

Comment: @StephenG I think you've confused wizards with lizards )

Comment: Seriously - [tag:reality-check] tag or [tag:magic] tag, please chose one. Otherwise magic-heat, do you want magic-heat?

Comment: Though its sad to have to say this - search for art for "*female* wizards". As many times, artists still render them with....let's say "clothing that is way better for warm weather" than their male counterparts

Comment: @Cumehtar Thanks for spotting the typo in time to edit comment.  The OP didn't give a species and I assumed that was a problem (does the OP really need help working out how humans keep warm or cold ?), and I think the typing part of my brain substituted "lizard" for "wizard" because my typing sub-brain has never gotten on well with the other bits and very much does it's own thing, as my posts probably demonstrate. :-)

Comment: Do it like JK Rowling for Harry Potter: Forbid him to use magic in the summer holidays. :-)

Comment: While [tag:reality-check] and [tag:magic] are usually mutually exclusive, I think they both worth here.  The RC is for human clothing in different conditions and the magic is to indicate the person's profession (which is relevant), status, and physical activity.  Remember, [tag:magic] isn't just for actual magic, it's the tag we use for "fantasy."  So totally relevant.

Comment: How about [bermuda shorts](https://www.awaltzthroughdisney.com/uploads/6/2/7/6/6276678/7634177_orig.jpg)?

Comment: [tag:reality-check] and [tag:magic] are not mutually exclusive.  To reality-check a magic question you must provide an entire scenario including the description of your magic system.  However, -1 because this does not meet the expectations of a reality-check question, which is to present a complete scenario for the community to judge.  In short, this is not a reality-check question.  I'd -1 a second time, if I could, for your use of the [tag:magic] tag as this question has nothing to do with magic (unless you haven't told us something?).

Comment: There is always the traditional sky clad!

Comment: I'm actually rereading the question yet another time, and I don't understand what exactly is OP asking. What would a robe-wearing wizard wear in summer? What would wizards living in subtropical and equatorial climates wear? What is optimal costume for a wizard (in which setting?)? What are the historical prototypes for wizardry robes? It's like so those questions rolled into one.

Answer (score 36):

Thinner robes? Seriously the broad brimmed hat is great for sunny weather or wet. If the robes are heavy wool they'll be almost water proof and plenty warm, thinner wool for cool spring and autumn weather and linsey-woolsey, a, usually, 50-50 blend of wool and the [flax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flax) fibre used to make [linen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linen) for the summer months in cooler climates, [cotton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton), linen or [silk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk) according to local availability where it gets really hot in the summer. The [Bedouin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedouin) of the Sahara traditionally wear pale colored linen robes and head scarves to help them survive the desert heat. By sticking to a clothing pattern and varying only the materials wizards won't find themselves unexpectedly encumbered by a change in the weather.

Comment: Some answers are too obvious.

Comment: @RonJohn Yes and no, if you have a clear expectation that says _this_ is what X looks like and _that_ is what they act like then it can be very hard to shift away from that perception.

Comment: That's a wizard robe, officer. Not a female dress. The floral pattern is there to help me better attune with nature.

Comment: I should rephrase: some *questions* have such obvious answers.

Comment: OP is so fixated. It's the same as if he asks, "Eskimos all wear thick furs, so what would they wear when it's warm?"

Comment: @RonJohn Yeah pretty much, it's obvious from the outside looking in but when you're thinking about it from a fixed point of view it isn't.

Comment: Which is why fixed thinking is so foolish.

Comment: @RonJohn Maybe but it's also impossible to look at a problem from anywhere but inside your own head unless you ask someone else and they point you at something new.

Comment: "*unless you ask someone else and they point you at something new.*"  That's complete rubbish.  Unless you consider "reading literature and getting educated" to be "ask(ing) someone else", which I don't.

Comment: @RonJohn It has the exact same effect with the downside that you have to know what you need to read and where to find it.

Comment: I didn't know what I needed to read when I started reading; I read what seemed interesting, and was ordered to do so (by school teachers) for other books.  It expanded my horizons without needing to ask a single soul about how to expand my horizons.

Comment: @RonJohn That's leisure reading not research. To get meaningful results reading for this kind of question you need to know you need to start, let alone where and how.

Comment: I just asked my 19 year old daughter, and then my aunt.  Neither of them did any "research".  Their immediate answers?  "Change into his cotton robe," and "seersucker" (a type of cotton fabric).  "It's common sense."  (They're both well-read.)

Comment: @RonJohn You are failing to understand what I'm trying to say, it does not matter one jot how much you have of anything if as long as you are asking from your own experience, or reading, there are things you cannot see.

Comment: And you're failing to understand that reading fiction (good fiction, not the drivel that now purports to be fiction) enlarges your experience.

Comment: @RonJohn It _does not matter_ how large your experience is you **_will_** have blind spots, be they large or small, and there will be questions that seem insurmountable from where you are sitting that I look at and can't understand why you're asking because it seems obvious, and vice versa.

Comment: Everyone will have blind spots, but this is a nonsensical one.  *Everyone* knows that you wear heavier clothes in the winter than in the summer.  (Well, everyone except maybe loin-cloth wearing, stone age hunter-gatherers living in equatorial low-land jungles whether the temperature never changes. But I bet they could figure it out, too.)

Comment: @RonJohn Or anyone from a tropical country, the tropics don't have seasons, by definition, or anyone from "the islands" where the weather is always warm and humid, or anyone from the arctic because by "warm" you obviously mean 2°C in which case heavy robes are still a necessity. There is no such thing as a "nonsensical blind spot" there is only one you have, or one you don't **_all_** blind spots look daft to someone.

Answer (score 29):

Lots of desert people wear long robes; if the sun is punishing enough, you'll want to cover up even if you are quite dark skinned. Loose fitting airy robes help keep you cool in those sorts of conditions, and by way of a bonus stop you getting too cold too quick when the sun sets, as in deserts the nights are often *cold*.

I won't try and ramble on here; images are the only really interesting things, and a) I'm finding it hard to locate really nice images worth showing you (because I'm a bit rubbish at image searching) and b) really, the photos will show a bunch of people in robes in interesting places. You don't really need to see them to know that yes, robes can and do work in very hot desert areas, and have been used for that exact purpose for well over a thousand years.

"Freedom of movement for casting" is ill defined, but constricting clothing is absolutely *not* what you want in very hot weather, so that's ok.

If your wizards want robes, then they can have robes. No problem

---

[image: Tuareg man]

Tuareg man. I think he's wearing cotton; certainly it appears to be quite a light fabric. [More info](http://www.imuhar.eu/site/en/imuhartuareg/clothing.php?lang=EN) on Tuareg clothing, plus links.

(as an unrelated footnote, Tuaregs are islamic but it is the *men* who wear the veils)

[image: Bedouin Sheikh]

Bedouin Sheikh. Note the black robes; when the sun is hot enough, the colour of your clothing doesn't really matter that much. White won't save you. Traditional bedouin robes were woolen, too.

And who could forget the classic strange bearded, robed guy with magical powers who lived in a desert?

[image: Alec Guinness as Obi Wan]

(it is little bit pointless for Jedi to wear those sort of robes if they live in non-desert environments, but somewhere along the way Lucas et al confused practical clothing with a uniform)

For use outside of desert climates, robes become increasingly less attractive as the weather gets wetter. A nice woolen cloak does an excellent job of keeping the rain off, but once you get inside you'll want to take it off. You will find some robes and robe-like garments in warm, wet locations however:

[image: Buddhist monk]

([Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=17384599))

Note the off-the-shoulder motif; not so good for stopping the sun, but not as stifling in hot, high-humidity conditions. You may also note how this style is often associated with people with strange and mystical powers...

Comment: remind me of spellfencer outfit in bravely default

Comment: Most deserts are cold at night, even those are hot by day can drastically drop temperatures since what keeps the air temperature warmth at night is umidity

Comment: I wish I could give you a second +1 for including space wizards in this answer.

Answer (score 14):

**The Gandalfesque wizard is a European wizard.**

Robes make sense if you are in England.  If you want a wizard from a hot climate, take a look at how people in that climate dressed historically when they wanted to put on a show and impress.  These Javanese performers are not wizards (I don't think) but their outfits would be great for a hot climate wizard: lots of skin, lots of ornaments, creepy masks.

[image: javanese performers]

You can find wizards from anywhere.  Googling around found Tahitians, Khmer, Indians; use search term sorcerer and you do better with African and pre-contact Americas. There is no shortage of amazing stuff for you to copy for your fiction.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the euro-centric bias of the question and giving an alternative.

Comment: @Cyn Gandalf is euro-centric, but the robes come from middle eastern desert cultures (though you'll certainly find analogues much further east), none of which are currently considered particularly european. The critical difference is that deserts have a wide temperature range with cold nights, whereas these folk come from hot, wet, tropical climates where the nights aren't bitterly cold and wearing large amounts of water-absorbing fabric is downright daft.

Comment: (though that said, you will find stuff like the [kasaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasaya_(clothing)) in warm, wet climates and associated with people who have strange, mystical powers... it does at least have an off-the-shoulder style so it'll be a bit more comfortable when the humidity is up)

Comment: The oldest references I found to hooded wizards were persian magi. Have a look at this guy's [robe and wand](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-JO_vFyalr1U/TE8wX8rXN-I/AAAAAAAAAQ0/FRHlTWdCgfo/s1600/MagusEdit.jpg). From something like 500 BCE in what is now eastern turkey.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yes, I could have worded it better I agree.  But the basics are still correct...robes are standard "wizard wear" in a small subset of the total world's area.

Comment: @Cyn very true, though the pedant in me would like to point out that _any_ wizard uniform is only standard in a small subset of the world's area ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The idea that a wizard wears a long robe is, surprisingly, a pretty old one. It's not a modern fantasy stereotype.

At least since the time of a Roman toga there was an implicit connection between long loose clothing and the lack of necessity to fight or work for a living.

In the 10th century the whole Europe started adopting Byzantine fashions, and we see kings in loose long robes on the miniatures, while fighting men and peasants wear shorter tunics. The Church had also adopted Byzantine fashions, so both Catholic and Orthodox priests and monks even now wear clothes that didn't change much from 10th century.

Free townspeople of high standing and scholars wore long robes in 15th century too.

In 17-19th century all the manners of loose silk robes of Eastern origin were worn as a part of domestic clothing by gentlemen of leisure, philosophers and writers. This banyan is an ancestor of a modern dressing gown and a bathrobe.

So we can conclude that the idea that an older man who doesn't need to fight or engage in other physical activity, but rather spends his time reading, writing, studying, teaching and discussing with other similar gentlemen, will wear long loose clothes, is entrenched enough in European culture that it doesn't need a reality check.

As for the materials, there are several ways to approach it. If we position medieval and not modern approach to sweat and body odor, you can continue wearing wool in a lot of environments. Ancient Greek and Roman clothes were mainly wool - and it gets pretty hot in Mediterranean. As other answers write, Bedouin clothes were traditionally wool.

If you are not afraid of your own sweat, wool is pretty comfortable when hot - maybe because it's a material more or less similar to human hair, being made from animal hair :)

Other materials like silk and cotton are already covered in other answers.

About the only environment you don't won't to wear wool in is warm and hot tropical. Buddhist monks still manage to wear long loose clothes there, even though it's rather a wraparound thingie and not a tailored robe.

UPD: as far as carrying the gear is concerned, in a medieval-ish world a wizard shouldn't carry all his gear with books and potions on his person. Just like a knight wouldn't always wear his armor and weapons. A knight would have a packhorse and a squire. A high-ranking wizard will have a mule and an apprentice to take care of that for him.

Comment: I think the "robed wizard" look came from Persian Magi (who were possibly Zoroastrians). Hard to find a reference to anything older, and they certainly seem to have been the origin of the idea of "magic" in Europe.

Comment: @StarfishPrime it's hard to pin down. 'Long robes and magical and spiritual powers' trope certainly existed by the Middle Ages. 'Eastern clothes and mystery' trope is older, true and was there at least as early as Late Roman Republic. 'Long clothes, age and respectability' is the oldest one in my opinion, and existed as early as Greeks.

Comment: Herodotus had stuff to say about the magi, and he was clearly using a latinised version of a greek version of their name.

Answer (score 3):

Using popular cultural as our guide, we only need to look at Disney for the wide range of sartorial options available to the modern magic user.

The traditional robe and pointy hats are suitable for everyday wear and official events too
[image: Tradition Merlin]

But, wizards are nothing if not adaptable and comfortable in any manner of dress.  Here we have Merlin strutting in the latest Bermuda fashions -- ensemble by Brooks Brothers of East Hollywood.

[image: Merlin in Bermuda]

Even a wizard as notable as Gandalf with rock the silk robe,  appropriate for a night on the town or hot Arabian nights
[image: Dandy Gandalf]

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the fashions of South American, African, SE Asian, and Pacific islander witch doctors, medicine men, shamans, sangomas, and whatever other names have been given to people claiming to use supernatural powers. Some of those are barely more than a loincloth. (With other paraphernalia added, often distinguishing their occupation: headdresses, bracelets, beads, staffs, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Comfort isn't always the most important thing, looking like you are what you are is also very important.

Think of medieval royalty and rich people, their outfits didn't really change summer or winter, as the point of the clothes was to be RICH, and to let every single person know they are  RICH

Is this a summer of winter outfit for for the queen, short answer both

[image: queen liz 1st]